# Linking to other column's hyperlink from title column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I have 2 columns "Name" and "URL" in my list view and showing only "Name" in a web part. Currently the column "Name" is set to linked to item with edit menu, I am trying to change the url for this Name column and pointing it to the URL value in my "URL" column.

I find the answers like using "linkToItem="TRUE" in Sharepoint Designer however my goal is to change the URL for a link which is pointing to edit menu, any suggestions? I am thinking between use Javascript to brutally change all values or using a calculated column to generate hyperlink, which would be a safe and faster solution?

Comment: Do you want Edit Item functionality with Edit Item link pointing to your new/custom URL from your URL column ? If yes then you can achieve this using CSR.

Comment: Refer this answer : https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/203041/can-force-the-titlelinked-to-item-with-edit-menu-column-inside-my-list-view/203053#203053

Answer (score 0):

You could use jslink:

```
(function () {
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        'Name': { 'View': myCustomView}
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
}) ();
function renderNameLink(ctx) {
    var itemURL = ctx.CurrentItem["URL"];
    var html = "<a href='" + itemURL + "'>linkName</a>";
    return html;
}
```